# Why does Unity fail to select a String constructor when resolving class?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, constructor-injection

I have upgraded Unity from v4.0.1 to v5.11.3 in a (.NET 4.5.2) project that worked fine before but since my upgrade I am getting the following exception: 
`Resolution failed with error: Failed to select a constructor for System.String`

The class I am trying to resolve has a String constructor and I have registered it with an `InjectionConstructor`. See code below:

```
// Multiple IDbContext registrations happen when the application is initialized
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, AuthenticationContext>(typeof(AuthenticationContext).ToString(), new InjectionConstructor(AppConstants.DatabaseKey));
container.RegisterType<IDbContext, ApplicationContext>(typeof(ApplicationContext).ToString(), new InjectionConstructor(AppConstants.DatabaseKey));

public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
   private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

   public DbContextFactory(IUnityContainer container)
   {
      _container = container;
   }

   public IDbContext CreateDbContext<TDbContext>() where TDbContext : IDbContext
   {
      var key = typeof(TDbContext).ToString();
      return container.Resolve<TDbContext>(key);
   }
}

public class AuthenticationContext : DbContextWrapper
{
   public AuthenticationContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
   {
   }
}

public class DbContextWrapper : IDbContext
{
   public DbContextWrapper(string connectionString)
   {
   }
}
```

How should I interpret the exception? Failed to select a constructor for String, makes me think the registration was successful and that it is looking for a constructor that accepts a String but cannot find it? Which is strange because my AuthenticationContext only has one constructor which accepts... a string!

I tried clarifying a full code example on dotnetfiddle, but there I am getting an "Operation could destabilize the runtime" exception when initializing the UnityContainer. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/xuX57K

Comment: In the meantime I have enabled the Unity debug mode using ```container.EnableDebugDiagnostic();``` which shows me a more detailed exception: ```The type System.String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value. Exception occurred while resolving:  String for parameter:  connectionString  on constructor:  AuthenticationContext(String connectionString)``` which I think I did with the ```InjectionConstructor```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the new exception message I got after enabling debug mode through `container.EnableDebugDiagnostic();` got me thinking... It's saying I must configure the container to supply the string value for the constructor, of which I am sure I did. So that implies it is actually not even considering using my registration. When debugging the container registrations I saw my registration was there so that could not be the problem either.

Then I realized that Unity registers all types by default so it was trying to create an instance of `AuthenticationContext` and hence it failed because when it uses an implicit registration it has no idea of what to do with the required string parameter.

The error is in the `DbContextFactory` and this fixed it:

```
public IDbContext CreateDbContext<TDbContext>() where TDbContext : IDbContext
{
   var key = typeof(TDbContext).ToString();

   // This is wrong because it is trying to resolve AuthenticationContext for a given name.
   // But it should resolve a registration for IDbContext for that name since that is
   // how it was registered!
   // return container.Resolve<TDbContext>(key);

   return container.Resolve<IDbContext>(key);
}
```